# Protractor Cucumber returning ScriptTimeoutError

Tags: angular, protractor, cucumber

I'm testing an Ionic app using Protractor and Cucumber, and I'm reusing a page object I've used in a previous test, but when I use it in this context, I get a `script timeout` error:

```
[14:40:32] E/launcher - script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.77)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600229 (3fae4d0cda5334b4f533bede5a4787f7b832d052),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
[14:40:32] E/launcher - ScriptTimeoutError: script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.77)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600229 (3fae4d0cda5334b4f533bede5a4787f7b832d052),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/Users/stuart/Documents/FamilyStoryUI/fsIonic/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/Users/stuart/Documents/FamilyStoryUI/fsIonic/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/Users/stuart/Documents/FamilyStoryUI/fsIonic/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:182:7)
From: Task: Protractor.waitForAngular()
    at thenableWebDriverProxy.schedule (/Users/stuart/Documents/FamilyStoryUI/fsIonic/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:807:17)
    at ProtractorBrowser.executeAsyncScript_ (/Users/stuart/Documents/FamilyStoryUI/fsIonic/node_modules/protractor/built/browser.js:425:28)
    at angularAppRoot.then (/Users/stuart/Documents/FamilyStoryUI/fsIonic/node_modules/protractor/built/browser.js:456:33)
    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/Users/stuart/Documents/FamilyStoryUI/fsIonic/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1376:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (/Users/stuart/Documents/FamilyStoryUI/fsIonic/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3084:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/Users/stuart/Documents/FamilyStoryUI/fsIonic/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3067:27)
    at asyncRun (/Users/stuart/Documents/FamilyStoryUI/fsIonic/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2927:27)
    at /Users/stuart/Documents/FamilyStoryUI/fsIonic/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:668:7
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:182:7)
```

Here's my cucumber step:

```
Given('a visit is scheduled for me', function(callback) {
  var world = this;

  casesPage.get()
    .then(() => {
      return casesPage.isLoaded()
    })
    .then(() => {
      return casesPage.clickOnCaseWithName(world.case.people[0].lastName);
    })
    .then(() => {
      return casePage.isLoaded();
    })
    .then(() => {
      return casePage.clickScheduleVisitButton();
    })
    .then(() => {
      return scheduleVisitPage.isLoaded();
    })
    .then(() => {
      return scheduleVisitPage.addAgenda();
    })
    .then(() => {
      return scheduleVisitPage.saveVisit();
    })
    .then(() => {
      return scheduleVisitPage.clickBackButton();
    })
    .then(callback);
})
```

And here's my page object:

```
import { browser, $, ElementFinder, ExpectedConditions } from 'protractor';

export class CasePage {

  caseHeader: ElementFinder
  visitNoteButton: ElementFinder
  scheduleVisitButton: ElementFinder
  nextVisit: ElementFinder;
  backdrop: ElementFinder;

  private initializePromise: Promise<void>;

  async initialize(): Promise<void> {
    if(!this.initializePromise) {
      return this.initializePromise = new Promise<void>(async (resolve) => {
        this.caseHeader = $('h2.family-name');
        this.visitNoteButton = $('button.start-visit-note');
        this.scheduleVisitButton = $('ion-col.schedule-visit button');
        this.nextVisit = $('div.next-visit');
        this.backdrop = $('ion-backdrop')
        return resolve();
      });
    }
  }

  async startVisitNote(): Promise<void> {
    await this.initialize();
    return browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(this.visitNoteButton), 1000).then(() => {
      return this.visitNoteButton.click();
    });
  }

  async clickScheduleVisitButton(): Promise<void> {
    await this.initialize();
    return browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(this.scheduleVisitButton), 5000).then(() => {
      return this.scheduleVisitButton.click();
    });
  }

  async isLoaded(): Promise<boolean> {
    await this.initialize();
    return await this.caseHeader.isPresent();
  }

  async familyName(): Promise<string> {
    await this.initialize();
    return await this.caseHeader.getText();
  }

  async nextVisitPresent(): Promise<boolean> {
    await this.initialize();
    return await this.nextVisit.isPresent();
  }

}
```

Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add allScriptsTimeout: timeout_in_millis to your Protractor configuration file. Default value is 11 seconds.  And if your app is not angular app, disable wait for angular.

```
exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 30000,
    ...
    onPrepare: function() {
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)
    }
};
```

Comment: No dice sadly. The element is there to click, but the script just hangs. It is an Angular app too.

Comment: @Pezholio, try to increase timeout seconds